# How to keep previous and current line if the previous line contains common text?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, paste

How to keep previous and current line if the previous line contains common text?

I have a main file like this:

```
Hello_world
Anna
Frank
Jeremy
Hello_earth
Jessie
James
```

I would want 3 output files like this:

**Output file 1** (Only has the string with the previous hello)

```
Hello_world,Anna
Hello_earth,Jessie
```

**Output file 2** (Only has the string WITHOUT previous hello)

```
Frank
Jeremy
James
```

**Output file 3** (Only has the string with the previous hello and including Hi to string without hello from previous line )

```
Hello_world,Anna
Hello_earth,Jessie
Hi,Frank
Hi,Jeremy
Hi,James
```

I have tried using grep and awk but was not able to get the desired output

Comment: So the common text is always 'Hello_'? Can there be no names between two hellos? Lastly, would be nice if you posted what you already tried with awk.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a GNU sed script. It uses the special 'W' (capital w) command, that appends to file only the first line, not the entire pattern space. This is used for the 'no_name' edge case, see below.

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -nrf

/^Hello_/{
    :new
        $b no_name
        N
        /\nHello_/b no_name
        b first_name
        :no_name
            s:^[^\n]+:&,:
            W output_1.txt
            W output_3.txt
            s:^[^\n]+\n?::
            /./b new
            $b other_names
        :first_name
            s:\n:,:
            w output_1.txt
            w output_3.txt
}
/^Hello_/!H
${
    :other_names
        x
        s:^\n::
        w output_2.txt
        /./s:^:Hi,:mg
        w output_3.txt
}
```

To test a few edge cases like the nonexistence of a name after the 'Hello_' keyword, I appended to the example input file: `Hello_foo\nHello_bar`. Output:

```
==> output_1.txt <==
Hello_world,Anna
Hello_earth,Jessie
Hello_foo,
Hello_bar,
==> output_2.txt <==
Frank
Jeremy
James
==> output_3.txt <==
Hello_world,Anna
Hello_earth,Jessie
Hello_foo,
Hello_bar,
Hi,Frank
Hi,Jeremy
Hi,James
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in gnu linux and freebsd:

```bash
sed '
  /^Hello/!b1
  N;s/\n/,/w file1
  b
  :1
  w file2
  s/^/Hi,/;H
  $!d;x
  s/^\n//
' file >file3
```

We write double lines to `file1` and output to stdout. We write single lines to `file2` and append to pattern space, which we output at the end to stdout and redirect to `file3`.